# Your project file doesn't list 'win10' as a "RuntimeIdentifier"... error when running Xamarin UWP project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, nuget

Here is the full error:

> Your project file doesn't list 'win10' as a "RuntimeIdentifier". You should add 'win10' to the "RuntimeIdentifiers" property in your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.

I opened up the csproj file in a text editor but I don't see any `RuntimeIdentifiers` property so I don't know where to add "win10"...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What I had to do is:

1. Create a brand new Xamarin app with a UWP project.
2. Copy the contents of my original UWP project's csproj file into a text editor
3. Copy the contents of the new UWP project file into the original.
4. Replace anything like project names and GUIDs that got overwritten with the original values.

Comment: can you use a diff tool (WinMerge) to show the difference to your original file?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: and what is now different between non working and working version?

Comment: what was the fix? as in what was in the diff? everybody is saying nuke the bin and obj.. but that apparently wasnt the answer.. sorry but -1 for not giving us the details... we need the details please. If you update you will get upvote back

Answer (score 15):

You can try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in the project, then restart VS and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 9):

Unload the `.csproj`, open it in editor and add this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-arm;win10-arm-aot;win10-arm64-aot;win10-x86;win10-x86-aot;win10-x64;win10-x64-aot</RuntimeIdentifiers>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Save the csproj, reload it in VS and run nuget restore.

Comment: Nope, I still get the same error. If I add "win10" to the `RuntimeIdentifiers`, I get an error saying I need .NET Framework...

Comment: try to delete the obj folder with the project.assets.json and the PROJECTNAME.csproj.nuget files and let VS regenerate everything.

Comment: I deleted the bin and obj folders and built the project again, but I still get this error. Are the project.assets.json and PROJECTNAME.csproj.nuget files located outside of obj?

Comment: they are located in obj folders. Here are some details about the file: https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/08/sdk-style-project-and-projectassetsjson.html

Comment: After editing your csproj file as indicated in this answer, right-click on the solution name and choose "Restore NuGet Packages".  Then do your build and you shouldn't get the error message.

Comment: It definitely fixed the case for me.    Thank you very Much

Answer (score 6):

same issue on my end. I was able to fix it by specifying platform target under the project's properties>Build. When I looked at it it didn't have anything selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the CPU architecture.
The option on toolbar that may say "Any CPU", if then please change it to your preferred architecture (e.g. I use x64, use x86)

[See the image for exact location of the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzTVq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found and fixed a very similar issue with a C# XAML app that showed the same error after adding arm64 target platform.
The fix was to upgrade the NuGet PackageReference for Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to be above version 6.2.x
Restore NuGets and it will then build.